# FTP over ssh hangs on "Connection established: Waiting for Welcome Message"

Tags: ssh, ftp, remote-access, vsftpd

I have looked far and wide and have not quite found the answer. I am running ubuntu 11.10, openssh, and vsftpd.

I am trying to configure my FTP to tunnel over ssh. My ssh connection works just fine and I can create the tunnel to my FTP port. When I go to use Filezilla to connect, it hangs at "Waiting for Welcome Message".

I think it is an iptables issue, but I can't seem to figure out what needs to be changed. When I take iptables down, it connects just fine. I don't want to open any more external ports, just my one SSH port, and I can't seem to get it right on the internal port forwarding rule. I always end up opening it to the outside.

I would love some help if anyone has any ideas and I hope I have made it clear. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You realise ssh has ftp builtin called sftp?  You just need a client capable of it like filezilla

Comment: Or even better, use nautilus -> connect to (ssh) server.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for sftp config files as i thought it was included, but I didn't see anything. Is there a way to configure it? Are they in the regular ssh etc folder somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In general a ftp client is using more than one port if it is using passive mode.
If you open the config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
and disable the passive mode with the parameter "pasv_enable=FALSE"

If your client needs the passive mode you can select the passive ports with the parameters pasv_max_port and pasv_min_port to a single port that you can forward through ssh too.